# BibDesk to Word via bibfuse: some coding

Tags: bibliographies, msword, bibdesk

I have recently started working with clinical colleagues who think LaTeX is a synthetic rubber used to make examination gloves, and have been forced to work with MS Word. In my Tex setup, I use BibDesk as my reference manager on a Mac OS, and have found [bibfuse](http://bibfuse.sourceforge.net) to be a nice way of citing papers in Word from BibDesk. The problem is that bibfuse seems to only be able to handle citing journal articles. It does not work very well at citing books, book entries (i.e., "incollection" entries in BibDesk), and websites. Does anyone know how to add to or modify the sampletemplate.doc file in the bibfuse package to accept these entries? The sampletemplate.doc file contains only the following lines of code:

```
<$publications>
<$itemIndex/>.  
<$pubAuthors.unpunctuatedAbbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingTeX.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAmpersand/> (<$pubFields.Year/>) <$pubFields.Title/>. <$pubFields.Journal/> 
<$pubFields.Volume/>, <$pubFields.Pages/>.
</$publications>
```

If no one knows how to do that, can anyone tell me what language this is, so I might figure it out and modify if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been playing with BibFuse, and have improved it for my own use.  It provides a very nice way to integrate Word with BibTeX (via BibDesk).  I am using it on Mac OS X.

You can get a lot of information from BiBDesk's help file (under the Appendix "Template Tags").  The language is Apple's Key-Value Coding.

Here is the template I have developed for my references:

```
<$publications>
<$pubType=article?>
<$authors.abbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAmpersand/> <$fields.Year.stringByAppendingCommaAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/><$fields.Journal.stringByDeTeXifyingString/>, <$fields.Volume.stringByRemovingTeX/>, <$fields.Pages.stringByAppendingFullStopIfNotEmpty/>
<?$pubType=inproceedings?>
<$authors.abbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAmpersand/> <$fields.Year.stringByAppendingCommaIfNotEmpty/> in <$fields.Series.stringByAppendingCommaIfNotEmpty/> Vol. <$fields.Volume.stringByAppendingCommaIfNotEmpty/> <$fields.Booktitle.stringByAppendingCommaIfNotEmpty/> ed. <$editors.abbreviatedName.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.stringByAppendingCommaIfNotEmpty.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAnd/> <$fields.Pages/>.
<?$pubType=book?>
<$authors.abbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAmpersand/> <$fields.Year.stringByAppendingCommaAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/><$fields.Title.stringByTeXifyingString.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces/>.
<?$pubType?>
<$authors.abbreviatedNormalizedName.stringByRemovingCurlyBraces.@componentsJoinedByCommaAndAmpersand/> <$fields.Year.stringByAppendingCommaAndSpaceIfNotEmpty/><$fields.Journal.stringByDeTeXifyingString/>, <$fields.Volume.stringByRemovingTeX/>, <$fields.Pages.stringByAppendingFullStopIfNotEmpty/>
</$pubType?>
</$publications>
```

This works for entries for articles, proceedings, and books.

This language is very sensitive to the syntax.  One misplaced character and it doesn't work!

Good luck!